# XML rendering issue

Tags: xml, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I got one encoding issue with XML rendering.The issue is ,when I am getting anglized  characters in XML tag like **ü** in  **Zürich** with XML 1.0 with UTF-8 encoding then it is not able to render it.
Example:
On rending XML Tag **Zürich** gives me **Z** only,following break in XML tag with encoding error issue.

**Please note** when I changed the encoding type from **UTF-8** to **iso-8859-1**,rendering/processing is happening appropriately.

I have 2 questions to get clarified:

1.UTF-8 being multi byte encoding technique it should be able to render anglized character also then why I am not able to do that?if UTF-8 can render these anglized characters also,then how it can be done using UTF-8?

2.Whether it is good practice to still prefer iso-8859-1 encoding technique over UTF-8 as UTF-8 has universal acceptance,covers a large set of characters including ascii/non-ascii?

Comment: Does your XML have utf-8 encoded on the top?

Comment: Did you actually change the XML file's encoding, or just the encoding declaration?

Comment: And what engine/tool/editor... has trouble rendering the file?

Comment: Yes Amarnath ,XML have utf-8 encoded on top.

Comment: Hi lenz,just changed the encoding declaration not the file's one

Comment: As far as rendering tool is concerned,I m using browser IE and Chrome

Comment: UTF-8 throughout.  Period.  End of discussion.  You apparently had `Zürich` rendered in iso-8859-1, but being read as if it were UTF-8.  UTF-8 barfed on it and told you so by throwing the rest of the string away.